# Binary search: first/last/random occurrence

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I've written some code to "binary search" a list, and return the **first occurrence** of the target:

```
def bsearch(a, left, right, target, first_or_last = 'first'):
    """
    Use binary search to find the first, last, or random index
    of target.

    >>> a = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
    >>> bsearch(a, 0, len(a)-1, 1, 'first')
    0
    """

    if left > right:
        return -1

    mid = (left + right)//2
    val = a[mid]

    if val == target:
        first_occur = mid
        if first_or_last == 'first'
            later_occur = bsearch(a, left, mid - 1, target)  # check if there's an earlier occurrence in the left sub-list
            if later_occur != -1:
                return later_occur
            else:
                return first_occur

        elif first_or_last == 'last':
            later_occur = bsearch(a, mid + 1, right, target)  
            if later_occur != -1:
                return later_occur
            else:
                return first_occur
        else:
            return first_occur

    if target < val:
        return bsearch(a, left, mid - 1,  target)
    if target > val:
        return bsearch(a, mid + 1, right, target)
```

Is there a more elegant/cleaner way to give this function the ability to find the **first, last, or random occurrence** of the target, without use of a string to represent the cases (as I've done)? Suggestions would be great.

Comment: Is there any reason why this can't be three functions: `bsearch_first()`, `bsearch_last()` and `bsearch_random()`?

Comment: @mleyfman: I'd like to avoid code duplication if possible. The only difference in these three functions is when each checks for equality and it would be great if we could generalize the search to allow for custom termination.

Comment: Last question: what do you mean by random? Do you mean a regular search?

Comment: @mleyfman: yes -- as soon as we find `target` in the list, we return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have the ability to choose between finding the first, last and a random occurrence of an element in a list. Since you have three options, you cannot use true/false, and numbers aren't very intuitive (and they usually end up magic numbers). The remaining options are strings, functions or some other data structure. Since you don't like strings, and other data structures wouldn't make much sense (why use a complex object when a simple one will suffice?), then let's stick to functions.

But wait, you don't want any code duplication. That's perfectly ok. We note that all 3 of these options involve variations of calling the basic binary search.

Let's create a basic binary search that outputs a few extras:

```
def _binary_search(array, element, low, high):
    """Binary search that returns (index, low, high) of the final search step"""
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        current_element = array[mid]
        if current_element == element:
            return (mid, low, high)
        elif current_element < element:
            low = mid + 1
        elif current_element > element:
            high = mid - 1

    return (-1, 0, 0)
```

Then, let's create the new functions:

```
def lower_bound(array, element):
    """Returns the index of the first occurrence of element in array"""
    index = -1
    first_index, low, high = _binary_search(array, element, 0, len(array)-1)
    index = first_index
    while first_index != -1:
        index = first_index
        first_index, low, high = _binary_search(array, element, low, first_index-1)
    return index


def upper_bound(array, element):
     """Returns the index of the last occurence of element in array"""
     index = -1
     first_index, low, high = _binary_search(array, element, 0, len(array)-1)
     index = first_index
     while first_index != -1:
         index = first_index
         first_index, low, high = _binary_search(array, element, first_index+1, high)
     return index


def binary_search(array, element):
    """Basic binary search"""
    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = len(array) - 1
    return _binary_search(array, element, lower_bound, upper_bound)[0]
```

This has the advantage of being readable, not susceptible to spelling errors ("First" vs "first" vs "fist") and not having much in the way of duplicated code.

---

As a fun fact: this entire problem can be easily solved by making wrappers around `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` from the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/bisect.html) like this very convenient `SortedCollection` Python recipe has done [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/).

**Update:**

1. Renamed functions to comply with standards as per comments
2. Changed algorithms to not create new arrays and instead do an in-place binary search
3. Changed algorithms to produce the correct results
4. Added reference to an easy to use Python recipe that implements this, and other features.

Comment: Even though it is python, I'd recommend to stick to `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, as they are blessed by mathematicians and used in STL.

Comment: @mleyfman: I like this a lot! I was hoping there would be some solution that involved functions and I think this is good!

Comment: @mleyfman: one thing that is worth noting is that we're creating a new array each time! this means that we'll be getting indices for the new array, and **not** the indices of the original array we wanted to search!

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. You will need to add/subtract from the original index (subtract for lower, add for upper). I'll post an updated solution this evening.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite good to know that [recursion is slow in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543019/why-is-recursion-in-python-so-slow) so if you can easily write something in a loopy way, it might be worth doing so.

Also, [passing a string parameter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) to tell which behavior is to be performed is a bit awkward. Apparently [Python has enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) but I didn't manage to make it work. Thus, on my side, I used an integer parameter whose sign is used to know which value is wanted. It is still a pretty bad solution but I haven't found any better.

Except for that, I haven't much to say about your code : variable names look good, code is properly documented, etc. You might be interested in my quickly written solution :

```
import math
# Result :
#  <0 : first
#  =0 : any
#  >0 : last
def binary_search(l, x, result=0):
    low, high = 0, len(l) - 1
    while low <= high:
        size = high - low
        mid_float = (low+high) / 2.
        mid = int(math.ceil(mid_float) if result > 0 else math.floor(mid_float))
        found = l[mid]
        if x < found:
            high = mid - 1
        elif x > found:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            assert x == found
            if result==0 or low==high:
                return mid
            elif result < 0:
                high = mid
            else:
                assert result > 0
                low = mid
        assert size > high - low
    return -1

def main():
    """Main function"""
    print("Hello, world!")
    for behavior in [-1, 0, 1]:
        assert binary_search([], 0, behavior) == -1
        r = range(10)
        for i in r:
            assert binary_search(r, i, behavior) == i
        assert binary_search(r, -1, behavior) == -1
        assert binary_search(r, 10, behavior) == -1

    l = [0] * 10
    assert binary_search(l, 0, 0) != -1 
    assert binary_search(l, 0, -1) == 0
    assert binary_search(l, 0, 1) == 9
    l = [0] * 10 + [1] * 10 + [2] * 10
    assert binary_search(l, 1, 0) != -1 
    assert binary_search(l, 1, -1) == 10
    assert binary_search(l, 1, 1) == 19
```

(Assertions make the code longer that it should be but safer is better).